# Solution for the JSTL's taglib is show on html page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

When I using JSTL in Spring, the view is show taglib tag like this.
[image]
This is my web config:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource(value = "config/application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true) })
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }


    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

JSP page content:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${title}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Have some good solution?

Comment: Did you add jstl library/dependency?

Comment: Yes I did, I am using jstl-1.2

Comment: And where is the `.jar` ?

Comment: Can you add your directory Structure Pic? + pom?

Comment: There are my structure, gradle file, and external dependences.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XpcZ.png
Gradle file
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlrt3.png
Dependences
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZRPY.png